# How can I change how PowerShell displays a property of my custom type?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell when I view my custom `MyStuff.Document` type in a table (or list) its `Content` property is not displayed using my `ToString()` function. Instead PowerShell iterates the collection and shows the items in it. I want it to use my `ToString()` function.

Example:

```
$doc = New-Object MyStuff.Document
$doc.Content.Add("Segment 1")
$doc.Content.Add("Segment 2")

$doc | select Content
```

It currently shows:

```
Content
-------
{Segment 1, Segment 2}
```

When I want it to show:

```
Content
-------
something custom
```

Where "something custom" is the output of my `ToString()` function.

I've dug into [`*.format.ps1xml`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847831.aspx) files which I think are what I need use but I can't figure out how to do what I want. [`Update-TypeData`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849908.aspx) also looked promising but I haven't had luck with that either yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

These are the custom types I'm working with:

```
namespace MyStuff
{
    public class Document
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public FormattedTextBlock Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class FormattedTextBlock : ICollection<FormattedTextSegment>
    {
        public void Add(string text)
        {
            this.Add(new FormattedTextSegment() { Text = text });
        }

        // ... ICollection implementation clipped

        public override string ToString()
        {
            // ... reality is more complex
            return "something custom";
        }
    }

    public class FormattedTextSegment
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

To be clear, I'm aware of strategies like `$doc | select @{ Expression = { $_.Content.ToString() }; Label = "Content" }`. I'm looking for away to tell PowerShell how to format my property by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two questions here.

First, when you do `Select -Property Content`, what you are really telling powershell is "Please give me a new object with the selected properties for further processing". This works so you can continue with the pipeline.

Second, if the pipeline ends, and there's nowhere else to put the data, formatting magic happens. For example `$doc | Select Content | format-table` will give the display you see now. What `format-table` receives however is a PSCustomObject with a dynamic type called `Selected.MyStuff.Document`. You could create magic type info for this, but since `Selected.MyStuff.Document` is dynamic, your format info would most likely be incorrect.

Alternatively, instead of select, you can do something like `$doc.Content.ToString()` assuming you have only one $doc, or if you have a collection of `MyStuff.Document` objects, `$doc | % { $_.Content.ToString() }`. These both lose the header.

If you want to format the entire MyStuff.Document object (no Select): `$doc | format-table`, you can use the following in a format.ps1xml file and magic happens. Note, I only implemented Format-Table for the MyStuff.Document type. You should be able to do something similar for your FormattedTextBlock.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <ViewDefinitions>
        <View>
            <Name>MyStuff.Document</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <TypeName>MyStuff.Document</TypeName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Name</Label>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Content</Label>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
                                <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
                                <ScriptBlock>$_.Content.ToString()</ScriptBlock> 
                            </TableColumnItem>
                        </TableColumnItems>
                    </TableRowEntry>
                </TableRowEntries>
            </TableControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really close to ideal. I wish PowerShell had a way to say "the default string representation for this type (`MyStuff.FormattedTextBlock`) should be `{ $_.ToString() }`". This is close though.